# LIMIT x, x and foreach do not work as expected

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I am using two php classes.

The first one is database connection class, which is the following: 
https://github.com/rorystandley/MySQL-CRUD-PHP-OOP

and seconds one is pagination class, which is the following: 
https://github.com/daveismyname/pagination/

My code:

```
            $db = new Database();
            $db->connect();

            $pages = new Paginator('30','page');

            $db->select('mods'); // Getting mods table
            $rows = $db->numRows(); // Get number of rows 

            $pages->set_total($rows); // Record number of rows to pagination class

            $db->select('mods', '*', null, null, null, $pages->get_limit() ); // Make request to the database 
            $mods = $db->getResult(); // Ger result from the database 

            foreach ( $mods as $key => $mod) { 
                $key += 1;
                echo '
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center">' . $mod['id'] . '</td>
                    <td data-id="' . $key . '">' . $mod['full_name'] . '</td>
                    <td class="text-center">' . $mod['short_name'] . '</td>

                </tr>
                ';
            }
```

By the documentation of pagination class I am doing everything correctly, however, I had to change this function `public function get_limit()`.

I have removed word `LIMIT` from there in order to use it in function `$db->select()` of database class. `select()` function is represented in this file - mysql_crud.php of database class from the link above on line `95`.

Main problem of the loop is about breaking data from the database into part. 
For example, if I break by 30 results, the first `?page=1` would give me all result from the database - so from `id=1` to `id=$rows`, `?page=2` would result of showing all results from `mods` table starting from `id=31` row and going up to `id=$rows`.

How can I fix this? Is it bug of the database class?

Thank you for help in advance!

Comment: I have soled my own problem. 

Here is it: 
This part of the code: `$db->select('mods'); // Getting mods table
            $rows = $db->numRows(); // Get number of rows ` should be like this: `$db->select('mods'); // Getting mods table 
$db->getResults();
            $rows = $db->numRows(); // Get number of rows` and before it did not work, because database class was mixed up with other values.